# Expandable div with buttons in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

That's my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2f6qscrp/311/
shortly: I've got a div that can be expandable and it reveals a new div. This kind of event must be in all div. So, in each section of this div I can open it (like an accordion). The problem is that if i click one of the buttons on this div (they must be there) the div opens. I would avoid this thing if possible. Is it possible?

```
<div ng-app='home'>
    <!-- App goes here -->
    <md-content md-scroll-y flex layout="column" class="_md ng-scope layout-column flex" layout-padding ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
         <div layout="column" md-scroll-y>
           <div layout="row" ng-click="showDetailsFunction();" class="div-outline-none div-cursor-pointer">
             <h3 flex class="div-card-panel-title">
               Blablablabla
             </h3>
             <span flex></span>
             <ul flex class="div-doc-act div-flex">
               <li>
                <md-button class="md-icon-button no-margin"
                   data-ng-click="doGreeting('btn1');">
                     btn1
                </md-button>
               </li>
               <li>
                <md-button class="md-icon-button no-margin"
                   data-ng-click="doGreeting('btn2');">
                     btn2
                </md-button>
               </li>
               <li>
                <md-button class="md-icon-button no-margin"
                   data-ng-click="doGreeting('btn3');">
                     btn3
                </md-button>
               </li>
             </ul>
           </div>
           <div data-ng-if="showDetails" class="animate-if">
              <div>
                wevniwernviurevnier
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

Angular part

```
angular.module('home', ['ngAria', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial']);

angular.module('home').config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('pink')
        .accentPalette('grey');
});

angular.module('home').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
        $scope.showDetails = false;
    $scope.showDetailsFunction = function() {
      $scope.showDetails = !$scope.showDetails;
    };
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
    $scope.doGreeting = function(greeting) {
        $window.alert($scope.greeting + " " + greeting);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using  `event.stopPropagation();` method  to avoid the div opening on the button click.

```
$scope.(your div name) = function($event) {
  $event.stopPropagation();
  // Some code to find and display the next image
}
```

Comment: If I use event.stopPropagation();  I can't use the functions in the buttons when I click over them

Comment: @End.Game oh yes! You still can. Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ahzhhuLw/.

Comment: I'm not sure. In my real code when I click one of the buttons starts a http call and if I put that code it doesn't fires the call. Also, the call opens a modal and with event.stopPropagation(); the modal not appears